# docker compose: unable to reference network alias over user-defined bridge network

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to facilitate communication between two docker containers that are created by different docker compose files. `ui-container` should be able to call and endpoint exposed on `api-container` via the docker network. Due to existing constraints, the api container has a container name that changes with each run, thus I need to find a different, constant way to reference the api container from the UI container.

I've established a bridge network between the containers, and I want to reference the API container by an alias which would remain static between runs. Here are the relevant parts of my two docker compose yamls:

my-backend-service docker compose:

```
services:
  api-container:
    image: 'my-api-image'

    networks:
      ui-bridge:
        aliases:
          - my-api-alias
      local:

    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

networks:
  local:
  ui-bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

my-ui-service docker compose:

```
services:
  django-app: 
    build:
      context: ./django-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev

    networks:
      - my-backend-service_ui-bridge

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  networks: 
    my-backend-service_ui-bridge: 
      external: true
      driver: bridge
```

Due to existing constraints, the api container name will always get a randomized name like `api-container-run-XXXXX`.

When I call the endpoint `http://api-container-run-XXXXX:5000` from the UI container, I am able to get a response, but when I try to reference the container by the alias with `http://my-api-alias:5000`, I get a connection error. Is there a way to make referencing the api container by alias work, or is there a different way that I have to do this?

Comment: I have a similar issue, with the fundamental difference being that my aliases are actually Traefik hostnames. I can communicate between containers spawned out of the main compose file, but cannot do so from containers spawned out of other compose files, even though they are on the same network. At a loss…